# Bootstrap the estimated GARCH volatility....for the two stage estimation

Tags: time-series, bootstrap, simulation, garch

GARCH(1,1) model is represented as
\begin{aligned}
x_t &= \sigma_t z_t, \\
\sigma_t^2 &= \omega+\alpha x_{t-1}^2+\beta\sigma_{t-1}^2, \\
z_t &\sim i.i.d (0,1).
\end{aligned}

If I want to uses estimated GARCH volatility as an input in some vector autoregressive model (VAR), I should incorporate the uncertainty of the GARCH estimates for the estimation of the VAR model. I could think of two ways of doing it.

**Alternative 1**

- Proposed bootstrap procedure is as follows.
  Estimate the GARCH(1,1) parameter $\theta= \{\hat{\omega},\hat{\alpha}, \hat{\beta}\}$.
  Draw $M$ samples of $\theta$ from their estimated distribution and simulate $\sigma^m_t$ using the equation 1, where $m$ is $1\dots M$.
  **It is important to highlight, that we are not simulating the $x_t$, rather than we use observed $x_t$ of the stock returns and pass that in the equation 1.**
  Now we have K sample of simulated volatility series for each of the stock, which we use to estimate the VAR model (K times).

**Is it a legitimate bootstrap method? If not, why?**

**Alternative 2**

- Bootstrap $K$ paths of the original time series ($x_t$) using block bootstrap. Then,  estimate the GARCH volatility for all $K$ time series. Then estimate the VAR model ($K$ times).

My question is, which of these methods is theoretically correct?
If both are wrong, what should be the correct way to do so?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? What are you trying to estimate? Knowing this is needed for justifying one or another set of assumptions underlying the methods you propose.

Comment: I am trying to explore the volatility spillover among the stock returns using VAR model...and for that I am extracting conditional volatility from the GARCH model

Comment: Consider modelling spillover effects with a multivariate GARCH model. It would be a cleaner approach methodologically, as you would not assume different properties of the time series at different modelling stages (this happens if you do it your way). But I do see the advantage of simple estimation of a VAR even for a high-dimensional time series and availability of LASSO and similar estimators. Are you following any particular textbook or paper?

Comment: There is however a problem with many of the popular multivariate GARCH models as the existence of the corresponding stochastic processes and/or the validity of the estimators are often questionable or even provably problematic. Michael McAleer and other authors have published some papers on that. I wonder myself which of the multivariate GARCH models can be trusted.

Comment: This is my own working [paper]{https://econpapers.repec.org/paper/iimiimawp/14613.htm}. Recently got the suggestion to bootstrap the GARCH estimates to incorporate the uncertainty at the first stage, not sure how to do it

Comment: If I am compelled to use the two step procedure... for some reason....which alternative is the best

Comment: Was that a question? Without the question mark, I am not sure how to interpret it. If it was a question, then it is a hard one, and I do not have a definite answer. There are multiple considerations to take into account.